# B2C Login process hangs on BrowserTabActivity - MAUI dotnet8 - Android 14 - MSAL nuget 4.59

Tags: android, maui, msal

I'm working on a MAUI app that uses Azure B2C Login for federated login. Everything was fine on Android versions up to 12 using .NET8 and up to Android 14 with .NET7, but on Android 14, it gets stuck on "BrowserTabActivity" without any errors showing up in the debug.

Here's a snippet from the Manifest.xml file:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    
    <application  android:allowBackup="true"
                  android:label="App Name"
                  android:usesCleartextTraffic="false"
                  android:icon="@mipmap/appicon">
      <activity android:name="microsoft.identity.client.BrowserTabActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
                android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
          <data android:scheme="msal<<<client_id>>>" android:host="auth" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="25" android:targetSdkVersion="34" />
    <queries>
      <intent>
        <action android:name="android.support.customtabs.action.CustomTabsService" />
      </intent>
    </queries>
```

I also tried an alternative method where the application enters OnCreate during the try executions, but it doesn't seem to do anything; perhaps it's failing to start the activity.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<application  android:allowBackup="true"
              android:label="App Name"
              android:usesCleartextTraffic="false"
              android:icon="@mipmap/appicon">
</application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="25" android:targetSdkVersion="34" />
<queries>
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.support.customtabs.action.CustomTabsService" />
  </intent>
</queries>
```

The MSALActivity class:

```
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

namespace Project.Platforms.Android
{
    [Activity(NoHistory = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop, Exported = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
        Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryBrowsable, Intent.CategoryDefault },
        DataHost = "auth",
        DataScheme = $"msal<<<clientId>>>")]
    public class MsalActivity : BrowserTabActivity
    {
    }
}
```

Has anyone faced such problem?

Comment: Please rephrase the question